# Why does the else statement still run when an if statement before runs?

Tags: c#, if-statement, console, console-application

When "wunschnote" isn't > 6 and < 1 so that none of the if statements runs it works, but as soon as one of the if stamemts runs, the else stamements also executes...

I tried to set the "Console.ReadLine();" inside of the if statements, but that leads to the same problem. Then I tried to make replace the else statement into a if statement, but that also leads to the same problem.

```
if (wunschnote > 6)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Der Wunschnitt kann nicht erreicht werden.\nDie Wunschnote müsste eine " + wunschnote + " betragen.");
}

if (wunschnote < 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Der Wunschnitt kann nicht erreicht werden.\nDie Wunschnote müsste eine " + wunschnote + " betragen.");
}

else
{
    Console.WriteLine("In der nächsten Probe muss eine " + wunschnote + " erreicht werden, damit der Schnitt von " + wunsschnitt + " erreicht wird.");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

I expect that when one of the if statements runs, the else statement won't get executet.

Comment: The second `if` should be an `elseif`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply `if else if` in your second condition for your case:

```
if (wunschnote > 6) { // this fails
}
else if (wunschnote < 1) { // then check this 
}
else { // if above if fails then this executes
}
```

Now in this case only one conditional block code will execute.

Answer (score 0):

Your else statement is valid only for the second if condition (<1). To make it applicable to the first if condition as well, you need to use a if-else if-else construct.

```
if(condition1)
{    }
else if(condition2)
{    }
else { }
```

With your code.

```
if (wunschnote > 6)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Der Wunschnitt kann nicht erreicht werden.\nDie Wunschnote müsste eine " + wunschnote + " betragen.");
}

else if (wunschnote < 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Der Wunschnitt kann nicht erreicht werden.\nDie Wunschnote müsste eine " + wunschnote + " betragen.");
}

else
{
    Console.WriteLine("In der nächsten Probe muss eine " + wunschnote + " erreicht werden, damit der Schnitt von " + wunsschnitt + " erreicht wird.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (wunschnote > 6 || wunschnote < 1)
    Console.WriteLine("Der Wunschnitt kann nicht erreicht werden.\nDie Wunschnote müsste eine " + wunschnote + " betragen.");
else
    Console.WriteLine("In der nächsten Probe muss eine " + wunschnote + " erreicht werden, damit der Schnitt von " + wunsschnitt + " erreicht wird.");
```